# Can't list an NFT using ME API

Tags: javascript, api, solana, nft

I have the API Key, and the request seems to go well, until the sendAndConfirmTransaction, in which it appears to expect 2 keypairs (mine, and what I'd assume is ME's), instead of just mine.

```
const Web3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
const axios = require('axios');

const bearerToken = ( 
); 
let secretKey = Uint8Array.from(
);
let keypair = Web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
const connection = new Web3.Connection(Web3.clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"), "confirmed");
//base58 wallet string to send in as params 
const wallet = keypair.publicKey.toBase58();
// Get buy instruction from API
axios.get(
  'https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/instructions/sell', {
    params: {
      seller: wallet, 
      auctionHouseAddress: 'E8cU1WiRWjanGxmn96ewBgk9vPTcL6AEZ1t6F6fkgUWe',
      tokenMint: 'AJ8N6ba6mnHYF1Vfce6rz7vEp5X1daPTsR8zDRBLBzie', 
      tokenAccount: '4WAzLxKPQNCCDMy51AAWoMyGrJmPCA9TDhAajjEXKzq1',
      price: 2.5 
      },
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + bearerToken }
  }).then((res) => {
      // sign and send txn here
      const txSigned = res.data.txSigned
      console.log(txSigned)
      const txn = Web3.Transaction.from(Buffer.from(txSigned.data))
      console.log(txn)
      const signature = Web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, txn, [keypair])
      console.log(signature)
  })
```

This is what I get:

```
{type: 'Buffer', data: Array(698)}
selltry.js:32
Transaction {signatures: Array(2), feePayer: PublicKey, instructions: Array(1), recentBlockhash: 'E1iTeBHU6DStbD1uoGQUeNGzxguz2QaVB8bQAEZ9vwkL', lastValidBlockHeight: undefined, …}
selltry.js:34
Promise {[[PromiseState]]: 'pending', [[PromiseResult]]: undefined, Symbol(async_id_symbol): 50, Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol): 21}
selltry.js:36
Uncaught Error Error: Signature verification failed
    at serialize (c:\Users\\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:1729:13)
    at sendTransaction (c:\Users\\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:9069:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
index.cjs.js:1729
Process exited with code 1
```

Any idea on what to do?